# Primitive roots as roots of a $q$-multinomial.

Tags: polynomials, q-analogs

If $n$ is divisible by $m$, why is it the case that the $m$th primitive roots of unity are also roots of $\binom{n}{k}_q$ if and only if $m$ does not divide $k$?

I'm viewing $\binom{n}{k}_q$ as a polynomial in $q$, but I don't see why the divisibility relations gives this condition of the primitive roots being roots of the polynomial. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complex $m$th roots of unity are roots of $x^m-1$, and form a regular $m$-gon on the unit circle in the complex plane with one vertex at $1$ (for $0 < m \in \mathbb{N}$). Primitive $m$th roots of unity are roots of the irreducible polynomial factors of $x^m-1$, called [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Cyclotomic_polynomials) $\phi_d(x)$ and satisfying
$$
x^m-1 = \prod_{0<d|m}\phi_d(x)\;,
$$
which recursively defines them: $\phi_1(x)=x-1$, $\phi_2(x)=x+1$, $\phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1$, $\phi_4(x)=x^2+1$, $\phi_5(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, $\phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1$, etc. In particular, $\phi_d(x)$ has degree [$\phi(d)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) and, as stated, its roots are precisely the primitive $m$th roots of unity.

(The polynomial factorization formula above can also be seen as providing a partition of the full set of $m$th roots of unity, which forms a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ of order $m$, into subsets based on their order -- for which *minimal* $d$ do they satisfy $x^d=1$ -- comprised of $\phi(d)$ generators $\{e^{2\pi ij/d}|(j,d)=1\}$ of the subgroup of order $d$ for each positive divisor $d$ of $n$. It is worthwhile once to draw some examples of these partitions.)

Now since
$$
[m]_q=\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}=\prod_{1<d|m}\phi_d(q)\;,
$$
its roots are precisely the nontrivial $m$th roots of unity for $m>1$ (all primitive $d$th roots of unity where $d>1$ and $d \mid m$).
So a root of
$$
\binom{n}{k}_q
=\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{[n-j+1]_q}{[j]_q}
=\prod_{1<d \leq n}\phi_d(q)^{e_d}
\qquad\text{for some }e_d\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
must be a root of the numerator more times than of the denominator (counting multiplicity). It is actually pretty elementary to calculate the $e_d$ (no prime factorization is needed). We simply observe that we need to add one for each time that $d$ divides a number from $\{n, n-1, \dots, n-k+1\}$ and subtract one for each time it divides a number from $\{k, k-1, \dots, 1\}$. This can be expressed using the floor function, by similar reasoning as is used to count powers in the prime factorization of a factorial:
$$
e_d
=\left[\frac{n}{d}\right]
-\left[\frac{n-k}{d}\right]
-\left[\frac{k}{d}\right]
$$
Observing that the each floor function is only taking away the residue or remainder modulo $d$ from the numerator of the fraction it contains, and grouping the two negative terms, we can see that $e_d\geq0$ is in fact positive iff $k$ has smaller (nonnegative) residue than $n$ modulo $d$. To see this, let $n=ud+r$ and $k=vd+s$ for $0 \leq r,s < d$ and note that
$$
e_d
=
\left[u+\frac{r}{d}\right]
-\left[u-v+\frac{r-s}{d}\right]
-\left[v+\frac{s}{d}\right]
=-\left[\frac{r-s}{d}\right]
=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & r < s \\
0 & r \geq s
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
since the floor function rounds down to $-\infty$ and $-d<r-s<d$.

In particular for $m=d \mid n$, we can see that the primitive $m$th roots of unity are roots of $\binom{n}{k}_q$ iff
$$
\phi_m(q) \mid \binom{n}{k}_q
\iff
e_m = 1
\iff
m \nmid{k}
\iff
m \nmid n-k
\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks bgins. Do you mind explaining further the case when $m\mid k$ if you have the time?

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thanks again bgins.